# Calculate the date of Easter Sunday

Tags: java, math

Write a program to compute the date of Easter Sunday. Easter Sunday is the first Sunday after the first full moon of spring.
Use the algorithm invented by the mathematician Carl Friedrich Gauss in 1800:

1. Let `y` be the year (such as 1800 or 2001)
2. Divide `y` by `19` and call the remainder `a`.  Ignore the quotient.
3. Divide `y` by `100` to get a quotient `b` and a remainder `c`.
4. Divide `b` by `4` to get a quotient `d` and a remainder `e`.
5. Divide `8 * b + 13` by `25` to get a quotient `g`.  Ignore the remainder.
6. Divide `19 * a + b - d - g + 15` by `30` to get a remainder `h`.  Ignore
   the quotient.
7. Divide `c` by `4` to get a quotient `j` and a remainder `k`.
8. Divide `a + 11 * h` by `319` to get a quotient `m`.  Ignore the remainder.
9. Divide `2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32` by `7` to get a remainder `r`. Ignore the quotient.
10. Divide `h - m + r + 90` by `25` to get a quotient `n`.  Ignore the
    remainder.
11. Divide `h - m + r + n + 19` by `32` to get a remainder of `p`.  Ignore the
    quotient.

Then Easter falls on a day `p` of month `n`.

For example, if y is 2001:

```
a = 6
b = 20
c = 1
d = 5
e = 0
g = 6
h = 18
j = 0
k = 1
m = 0
r = 6
n = 4
p = 15
```

Therefore, in 2001, Easter Sunday fell on April 15.

Make sure you prompt the user for a year and have the user input the year.  Also, make sure you output the values of p and n with the appropriate messages describing the values output.

---

I'm having a little trouble putting this into Java code. Here's what I've tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Easter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int y = 2014;
        int a = y % 19;
        int b = y / 100;
        int c = y % 100;
        int d = b / 4;
        int e = b % 4;
        int g = (8 * b + 13) / 25;
        int h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
        int j = c / 4;
        int k = c % 4;
        int m = (a + 11 * h) / 319;
        int r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7;
        int n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25;
        int p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;

        getEasterSundayMonth = n;
        System.out.println("Month: " + Easter.getEasterSundayMonth());
    }
}
```

This is what I have. I don't know how to assign stuff, like I tried to get `getEasterSundayMonth` to equal the value of `n`, pretty sure its not right. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Yes that would definitely help me, thats one of the things i'm asking. A push in the right direction would be lovely since i cannot ask my professor much at all.

Comment: Ummm... it looks like you're done. You just need to print p and n to the screen and specify what they are - System.out.println("Month: " + n);

Comment: Thank you rock i will definitely do that, but azure is right. My professor is hard, legitimately very difficult with how he grades. How would i prompt the user?

Comment: `int y = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Is anyone else not getting the correct date with this method? For 2001 I got `p = 8.82`which is nowhere near 15. I just copied the logic and put it in the chrome console. For 2014 I got `p = 14.8112`, but it occurred on the 20th.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Easter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday\n>");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputted = getResult(s);
        while(inputted <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Expected a positive year. Please try again:\n>");
            inputted = getResult(s);
        }
        System.out.println(getEasterSundayDate(inputted));
    }

    private static int getResult(Scanner s)
    {
        while(!s.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.print("Expected a valid year. Please try again:\n>");
            s.nextLine();
        }
        return s.nextInt();
    }

    public static String getEasterSundayDate(int year)
    {
        int a = year % 19,
            b = year / 100,
            c = year % 100,
            d = b / 4,
            e = b % 4,
            g = (8 * b + 13) / 25,
            h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30,
            j = c / 4,
            k = c % 4,
            m = (a + 11 * h) / 319,
            r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7,
            n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25,
            p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;

        String result;
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
                result = "January ";
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "February ";
                break;
            case 3:
                result = "March ";
                break;
            case 4:
                result = "April ";
                break;
            case 5:
                result = "May ";
                break;
            case 6:
                result = "June ";
                break;
            case 7:
                result = "July ";
                break;
            case 8:
                result = "August ";
                break;
            case 9:
                result = "September ";
                break;
            case 10:
                result = "October ";
                break;
            case 11:
                result = "November ";
                break;
            case 12:
                result = "December ";
                break;
            default:
                result = "error";
        }

        return result + p;
    }
}
```

An input of `2001` results in `April 15` as the output.

Comment: This comment correctly answers the question/assignment which states to use Gauss's 1800 calculation.  As a warning to those who might stumble on this answer looking for an algorithm to calculate Easter, be aware Gauss's method is only guaranteed for the 18th and 19th century.   You might prefer to use another method (e.g., Anonymous Gregorian) to ensure accuracy in the 20th century and beyond.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus

Answer (score 4):

You aren't far from getting your program working.  You really have two things left you need to do.

- Prompt the user for a year
- Output the date found

The trick to using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to prompt the user for input is to create a while-loop which tests each line the user enters, and keeps repeating until it sees a legal value.

Instead of hard-coding `y = 2014;` (or whatever), you want to do something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int y = -1;  // No easter back in B.C.
while (y < 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a year (integer greater than zero)");
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {    // check to see if the user entered a number
        y = input.nextInt();     // if so, read it
    }
    input.nextLine();            // advance the scanner to the next line of input
}
```

in this case, each time the user doesn't enter a number, `y` remains `-1` and the loop continues.

You are already doing all the calculations correctly, so to end your program, you just need to output the month/day.

I wouldn't bother trying to extract the calculation into a helper method.  Just use the calculated values directly in `main()`:

```
int a = y % 19;
int b = y / 100;
...
int n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25;
int p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;
System.out.println("In the year " + y + " Easter with fall on day " + p + " of month " + n);
```

Comment: You should link to the Java 8 documentation instead of Java 7.

Comment: I prefer the helper method as it allows programs to determine a particular output instead of strictly being tied to the human input.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Generally so do I, but the point of this homework assignment seems to be to learn about arithmetic on primitives, and basic input and output, so that's what I focused my answer on.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for the updated version (NY Anonymous Gregorian) of the algorithm in Typescript...

```
easterDate() {
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var a = Math.floor(currentYear % 19);
  var b = Math.floor(currentYear / 100);
  var c = Math.floor(currentYear % 100);
  var d = Math.floor(b / 4);
  var e = Math.floor(b % 4);
  var f = Math.floor((b + 8) / 25);
  var g = Math.floor((b - f + 1) / 3);
  var h = Math.floor((19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30);
  var i = Math.floor(c / 4);
  var k = Math.floor(c % 4);
  var l = Math.floor((32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) % 7);
  var m = Math.floor((a + 11 * h + 22 * l) / 451);
  var n = Math.floor((h + l - 7 * m + 114) / 31);
  var p = Math.floor(((h + l - 7 * m + 114) % 31) + 1);
  // console.log('a: ' + a + ' b: ' + b + ' c: ' + c + ' d: ' + d + ' e: ' + e);
  // console.log('f: ' + f + ' g: ' + g + ' h: ' + h + ' i: ' + i + ' k: ' + k);
  // console.log('l: ' + l + ' m: ' + m + ' n: ' + n + ' p: ' + p);
  // console.log("In the year " + currentYear + " Easter with fall on day " + p + " of month " + n);
  var month = n.toString();
  while (month.length < 2) month = "0" + month;
  var day = p.toString();
  while (day.length < 2) day = "0" + day;
  var dateString = currentYear.toString() + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T00:00:00';
  return new Date(dateString);
}
```

Comment: Quentin Tarantino: Where are the types? xD Where are the const's?

Answer (score 1):

```
VisualBasic Excel VBA Code

Function Easter_Sunday(Year)
    k = Int(Year / 100)                                         'the secular number
    s = 2 - Int((3 * k + 3) / 4)                                'the secular sun control
    m = 15 + Int((3 * k + 3) / 4) - Int((8 * k + 13) / 25)      'the secular moon circuit
    a = Year Mod 19                                             'the lunar parameter
    d = (19 * a + m) Mod 30                                     'the seed for the first full moon in spring
    r = Int(d / 29) + (Int(d / 28) - Int(d / 29)) * Int(a / 11) 'the calendar correction amount
    EB = 21 + d - r                                             'the Easter border
    FS = 7 - (Year + Int(Year / 4) + s) Mod 7                   'the first Sunday in March
    ED = 7 - (EB - FS) Mod 7                                    'Easter distance in days
    ESM = EB + ED - 1                                           'the date of Easter Sunday as the March date

    '--------------------------------------- "For Years (1900-9999)" ------------------------------
    Easter_Sunday = DateValue(1 & "." & 3 & "." & Year) + ESM

    '--------------------------------------- "or for all Years" -----------------------------------
    Month_ = 3 + Int(ESM / 31)               'Month March or April
    ES = 1 + ESM Mod 31                      'Eastersunday

    Easter_Sunday = ("Su, " & Year & "." & Format(Month_, "00") & "." & Format(ES, "00"))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

```
private fun getEasterSundayDate(year: Int): String {
        val a = year % 19
        val b = year /100
        val c = year % 100
        val d = b /4
        val e = b % 4
        val g = (8 * b + 13) / 25
        val h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30
        val j = c / 4
        val k = c % 4
        val m = (a + 11 * h) / 319
        val r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7
        val month = (h - m + r + 90) / 25
        val day = (h - m + r + month + 19) % 32

        return String.format("%02d", day) + "." + String.format("%02d", month)
    }
```

Comment: I'd return a LocalDate instance instead of a String.  Love the Kotlin version, though.

Answer (score 0):

...or someone needs it in ColdFusion:

```
<!---
    Function to get the easter date adopted to ColdFusion as of
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022233/calculate-the-date-of-easter-sunday
--->
<cffunction name="getEasterDate">
    <cfargument name="year" required="true">
    <cfscript>

        var currentYear = arguments["year"];

        var a = floor(currentYear % 19);
        var b = floor(currentYear / 100);
        var c = floor(currentYear % 100);
        var d = floor(b / 4);
        var e = floor(b % 4);
        var f = floor((b + 8) / 25);
        var g = floor((b - f + 1) / 3);
        var h = floor((19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30);
        var i = floor(c / 4);
        var k = floor(c % 4);
        var l = floor((32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) % 7);
        var m = floor((a + 11 * h + 22 * l) / 451);
        var n = floor((h + l - 7 * m + 114) / 31);
        var p = floor(((h + l - 7 * m + 114) % 31) + 1);

        var month = n;
        if (len(month) lt 2) {
            month = "0" & month;
        } 

        var day = p;
        if (len(day) lt 2) {
            day = "0" & day;
        }

        var dateString = day & '.' & month & '.' & currentYear;

        return dateString;

    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Orthodox easter formula, invented back in 1800 by famous Carl Friedrich Gauss.
 */
public static LocalDate getEasterSundayDate(int year) {
    int a = year % 19,
            b = year / 100,
            c = year % 100,
            d = b / 4,
            e = b % 4,
            g = (8 * b + 13) / 25,
            h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30,
            j = c / 4,
            k = c % 4,
            m = (a + 11 * h) / 319,
            r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7,
            month = (h - m + r + 90) / 25,
            day = (h - m + r + month + 19) % 32;

    return LocalDate.of( year, month, day );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of easter calculation by Carter's formula, which should work for years between 1900 and 2099 (formula taken from [here](https://www.rmg.co.uk/stories/topics/when-easter#:%7E:text=The%20simple%20standard%20definition%20of,Easter%20is%20the%20next%20Sunday.))

```
fun easter(year: Int): LocalDate {
    var d = 225 - 11 * (year % 19)

    while (d > 50) {
        d -= 30
    }

    if (d > 48) {
        d -= 1
    }

    val e = (year + year / 4 + d + 1) % 7
    val q = d + 7 - e

    return if (q < 32) {
        LocalDate.of(year, Month.MARCH, q)
    } else {
        LocalDate.of(year, Month.APRIL, q - 31)
    }
}
```

And, actually for the orthodox easter there is a different formula (from [here](https://planetcalc.com/4213/))

```
fun easterOrthodox(year: Int): LocalDate {
    val a = year % 19
    val b = year % 4
    val c = year % 7
    val d = (19 * a + 15) % 30
    val e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 6) % 7
    val f = d + e
    val date = if (f <= 9) {
        LocalDate.of(year, Month.MARCH, 22 + f)
    } else {
        LocalDate.of(year, Month.APRIL, f - 9)
    }
    return date.plusDays(13)
}
```

Both formulas tested to match these dates - [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dates_for_Easter).