# Program worked fine, but now i cant spot the error

Tags: java

I ran the program and it was working fine and i dont know what i did, but this is what i get in the dialog box. It should say April 5 not error5

```
Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday
>2015
error5
```

Can anyone spot where the error is from? and also another question is do i need all the case 1-12 and all the months? Or can i just get by with april since its the only month im using to calculate easter sunday.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Easter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday\n>");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputted = getResult(s);
        while(inputted <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Expected a positive year. Please try again:\n>");
            inputted = getResult(s);
        }
        System.out.println(getEasterSundayDate(inputted));
    }

    private static int getResult(Scanner s)
    {
        while(!s.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.print("Expected a valid year. Please try again:\n>");
            s.nextLine();
        }
        return s.nextInt();
    }

    public static String getEasterSundayDate(int year)
    {
        int a = year % 19,
            b = year / 100,
            c = year % 100,
            d = b / 4,
            e = b % 4,
            g = (8 * b + 13) / 25,
            h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30,
            j = c / 4,
            k = c % 4,
            m = (a + 11 * h) / 319,
            r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7,
            n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25,
            p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;

        String result;
        switch(n)
        {
        case 1:
                result = "April ";
                break;

            default:
                result = "error";
        }

        return result + p;
    }
}
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like dumping out the value of `n` when you hit the `default` case?

Comment: I don't have a Java compiler on-hand, but defining those letter variables all one line seems odd. Is it guaranteed that they'd be initialized in order so their values are as expected?

Comment: Your variable names need to be more descriptive than they are now.  `n` may have context now, but what about at 9AM?  It'd also help to, in your `default` statement, print out that variable to see its value.

Comment: closed and reopened eclipse, well it works again. I don't understand that to be honest but maybe this is a situation where i should just accept what happened and move on haha. I sat there and re-ran it so many times and got the same error but well its fine now.

Comment: Seems the error comes from when i get rid of all the only months and keep on the april content. Can anyone explain why i need the other months? I'm new to java

Comment: @DevinWesolowski What do you mean when you say "Get rid of the months"?

Comment: I should mention that the code that the OP has provided here is **[my code that I wrote to answer another question of his](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022233/calculate-the-date-of-easter-sunday/26022891#26022891)**. You guys need to read that question to understand this one.

Comment: @Makoto It's not his *own* code. See my above comment.

Comment: Yes damry is the one of those who originally helped me with my problems, but i couldnt find if this site has a messaging feature to re-ask him about it. By the months thing, i dont seem to understand why i need the remaining months when i'm only calculating an easter sunday, which can only appear in april im pretty sure. Was just trying to shorten the code

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi:  It looks like to me that they're taking it as if it's their own.  If they don't feel it prudent to make the code at least more readable for their own edification, then their copy-paste habits will bite them hard.  And it seems like it's doing so now.

Comment: @DevinWesolowski What was your code when you attempted to remove the cases for the months other than April? Please **edit it into the question**.

Comment: I edited my OP to what it looks like when i get rid of the other months. This gives the result of "error20" When you type in 2014, when it should produce "April 20"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple typo.

Your switch statement looks like this:

```
switch(n)
{
    case 1:
        result = "April ";
        break;

    default:
        result = "error";
}
```

Remember that the number for the month is `n`, so if `n` is 4, then that means that the found month is April. However, in this code, you're treating the April case as `n` being *1*, not 4. As such, as your program is *calculating* `n` to be 4, it is not covered by `case 1:` and is thus causing `error` instead of `April` to appear in the output. Change that switch statement to this:

```
switch(n)
{
    case 4:
        result = "April ";
        break;

    default:
        result = "error";
}
```

Now, notice that I'm using `case 4:` instead of `case 1:` to properly find the April case.

However, if you're just using one case like this, it is better to merely use an `if` statement than a `switch`:

```
if(n == 4)
    result = "April ";
else
    result = "error";
```

On the other hand, when you're checking for a lot of cases like before, you should use a `switch`.

However, I still think you should still consider the cases for other months since it doesn't state in your original homework problem in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022233/calculate-the-date-of-easter-sunday/) that Easter Sunday is always in April.

Comment: You are honestly incredible, i get so flustered with this stuff but the way you were able to explain it i actually understand what you are talking about. Thank you so much for all of your help!