# Java Easter calculator for 2016 using the Gauss algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm making Easter Sunday calculator using the [Gauss algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Gauss_algorithm) for the next 10 years.

It seems to work fine except several years. For example it tells that in 2016 Easter will be on 2016-03-27, but it will be on the 2016-05-01. It works fine with other years.

This is my code:

```
public class EasterCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EasterCalculator obj = new EasterCalculator();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyy");

    for (int i = 2016; i < 2026; i++) {
        System.out.println("Easter  in " + i + " will be on " + obj.getEasterDate(i).format(formatter));
        System.out.println("Trinity in " + i + " will be on " + obj.getEasterDate(i).plusWeeks(7).format(formatter));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public LocalDate getEasterDate(int year) {
    int a = year % 19;
    int b = year % 4;
    int c = year % 7;
    int k = year / 100;
    int p = (13 + 8 * k) / 25;
    int q = k / 4;
    int M = (15 - p + k - q) % 30;
    int N = (4 + k - q) % 7;
    int d = (19 * a + M) % 30;
    int e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + N) % 7;

    if (d == 29 && e == 6) {
        return LocalDate.of(year, 3, 22).plusDays(d + e).minusDays(7);
    } else
        return LocalDate.of(year, 3, 22).plusDays(d + e);
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, so have you gone through the algorithm on paper and compared it with the equivalent steps in the debugger? Do you know that the Gauss algorithm is correct for 2016?

Comment: i calculated in on paper - it gave me the same steps as Java program. But the date is still wrong. So doesn't Gauss algorithm work for 2016?

Comment: Gauss himself said it was only valid for the 18th and 19th centuries.

Comment: See [Calculate the date of Easter Sunday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022233/calculate-the-date-of-easter-sunday).

Comment: oh i see. Thanks. But in some cases it still works.

Comment: see [easter 2016](http://www.wheniseastersunday.com/year/2016/) acording to that and some other calendars including mine own it is 27.3.2016

Comment: If you only need it to work for ten years, why not just use an array? `(2016-03-27, 2017-04-16, 2018-04-01, 2019-04-21, 2020-04-12, 2021-04-04, 2022-04-17, 2023-04-09, 2024-03-31, 2025-04-20)`. By the way, 2016-04-01 will be a Friday. Easter usually falls on a Sunday.

Comment: I saw it in some russian calendar: http://azbyka.ru/paskha/pravoslavnaya_pashaliya-all.shtml
i misspelled - 1 of May! Of course Easter comes on Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.wheniseastersunday.com/year/2016/) and [this](http://www.primarygames.com/holidays/easter/when_is_easter.php) Easter Sunday is on 2016-03-27. I also tested your code and it seems to work. I do not know if I misunderstood your question, but it seems to me, that Gauss is still right.

**Edit:** 
after some research and the comment of the author, I learned that the western Easter and the orthodox Easter are not necessarily on the same date (see [here](http://www.gmarts.org/index.php?go=413)). As you can see, there are several matches but mostly not. As Gauss was a German mathematician, it appears that he developed the algorithm for western Easter.

Comment: So you are saying you can not reproduce the problem?

Comment: Actually there is no problem with the algorithm. The algorithm gives you the date of the western eastern. If you are looking for the orthodox eastern you might use a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The Gauss algorithm fails for some western Easter dates:
1954-04-18 (Gauss: 1954-04-25)
2049-04-18 (Gauss: 2049-04-25)
2106-04-18 (Gauss: 2106-04-25)

According to french Wikipedia the algorithm Butcher-Meeus is correct:
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcul_de_la_date_de_P%C3%A2ques

```
public LocalDate getEasterDateMeeus(int year) {
    int a = year % 19;
    int b = year / 100;
    int c = year % 100;
    int d = b / 4;
    int e = b % 4;
    int f = (b + 8) / 25;
    int g = (b - f + 1) / 3;
    int h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
    int i = c / 4;
    int k = c % 4;
    int l = (32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) % 7;
    int m = (a + 11 * h + 22 * l) / 451;
    int easterMonth = (h + l - 7 * m + 114) / 31;
    int p = (h + l - 7 * m + 114) % 31;
    int easterDay = p + 1;
    return LocalDate.of(year, easterMonth, easterDay);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Any other source about this error into Gauss algorithm?