# where is the issue within my easter calculator program?

Tags: java

Can't find the calculation issue within my easter calculator program. If the input is 2019, the month output is 4, and day is -2 for some reason. 4 would be April which is correct but the day is wrong. Advice to make the code more efficient and solution?

[image]

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.Math;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Easter Calculator. Please enter the current year below.");
    double y = userInput.nextInt();

    double p = y/100;

    double q = y - (19*(y/19));

    double r = (p-17)/25;

    double s = p - (p/4) - ((p-r)/3) + (19*q) + 15;

    s = s - (30*(s/30));

    s = s - ((s/28)*(1-((s/28)*(29/(2+1))*((21-q)/11))));

    double t = y + (y/4) + s + 2 - p + (p/4);

    t = t - (7*(t/7));

    double u = s - t;

    double m = 3 + ((u+40)/44);

    double d = u + 28 - (31*(m/4));

    System.out.println("Year = "+Math.round(y));
    System.out.println("Month = "+Math.round(m));
    System.out.println("Day = "+Math.round(d));
  }
}
```

Comment: s = s - ((s/28)*(1-((s/28)*(29/(2+1))*((21-q)/11)))); Here is the mistake... there should be (29/(s+1)) instead of (29/(2+1)). FOr verification, check the image you attachedd. It contain the correct formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to simply convert all variable types from doubles to integers. Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Easter Calculator. Please enter the current year below.");
int y = userInput.nextInt();

int p = y/100;

int q = y - (19*(y/19));

int r = (p-17)/25;

int s = p - (p/4) - ((p-r)/3) + (19*q) + 15;

s = s - (30*(s/30));

s = s - ((s/28)*1-((s/28)*(29/(s+1))*((21-q)/11)));

int t = y + (y/4) + s + 2 - p + (p/4);

t = t - (7*(t/7));

int u = s - t;

int m = 3 + ((u+40)/44);

int d = u + 28 - (31*(m/4));

System.out.println("Year = "+Math.round(y));
System.out.println("Month = "+Math.round(m));
System.out.println("Day = "+Math.round(d));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the third line of `s` calculation

```
s = s - ((s / 28) * (1 - ((s / 28) * (29 / (2 + 1)) * ((21 - q) / 11))));
```

you have phrase `(29 / (2 + 1)` which is itself suspicuous and does not correspond to the notes you've attached. There should be `(29 / (s + 1)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I've tried this and unfortunately made no difference, the output is still : month =4, day = -2 if the input is 2019

Answer (score 0):

Constructions like

`y - (19 * (y / 19))`

`t - (7 * (t / 7))`

`s - (30 * (s / 30))`

will always produce practical `0` been calculated in double all through. 
There should be an integer division in brackets.

Is there any note to the page you quoted?

If we assume here we calculate sort of scaled operational margin, and use int division like this

`y - (19 * (((int)y) / 19))` or `y - (19 * (int)(y / 19))` (which delivers smaller delta)

in all these places, we'll get 17-th of April for 2019. Looks valid data, but not valid Easter date for the year (not sure about that, actually).

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207763/java-easter-calculator-for-2016-using-the-gauss-algorithm

Comment: If the intent is for this to be integer division, changing all of the variables from double to int might suffice.

Comment: Int-variabled solution does not lead to a valid answer either.  My point is that we have to know more about the algorithm, not just an arithmetic script. Programming part is ok, but the logic of calculations is unclear. Here is the investigation trigger for the author.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've actually fixed the program by changing all the variable types from double to int. For some reason integers work even though throughout the calculations, I thought the integers would've been converted to doubles. Thanks for the help!