# Jollyday Checking Easter

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Backing up one step from the question - I am trying to not have to reinvent the wheel on writing a Date checker for Java.

I stumbled onto [Jollyday](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/) which is referenced from the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) site.

My question is, does anyone know how to get it to return Easter as a Holiday?

When I instantiate:

```
    HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayCalendar.UNITED_STATES);
    Set<Holiday> holidays = m.getHolidays(2016, "ny");
```

I get a nice list of Holiday objects that are iterable - but, Easter is missing.

Does anyone have any experience with this library or know how to get it to return a full list of Holidays?

Comment: I'd guess that either the list of holidays is not complete or easter is not considered a holiday.

Comment: Looking at the usage page (http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/usage.html) it would seem you need to define the public holidays yourself in an xml file. Have you done that?

Comment: Looking again I can see the project author has provided ready made xml files for use. Have you used the American one provided?

Comment: There are multiple dates for Easter, depending on the variant of Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to [configure](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/properties.html) Jollyday and then [load configuration](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/usage.html) in code. Code examples are on links I provided. Problem with Easter is that it's not fixed day, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022233/calculate-the-date-of-easter-sunday) you can find question about how to count it and [here is note](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/EastercomputethedayonwhichEasterfalls.htm) why it works only after year 1583.